# Excel Power Query _count how many products have per size

Tags: excel, powerquery

in excel power query i have product ,size and stock. I would like to count how many products have stock only to in  1 size,only to in 2 sizes, only to in 3 sizes etc.

thanks in anvance

the desired result

[image: the desired result]

datasample

[image]

Comment: A small example with desired result would be useful. Also, are you sure you want to perform these counts within Power Query? Or using DAX? How are your results to be displayed?

Comment: Countifs() or sumifs() may work, but you don't show any data.

Comment: i have added  an image with the desired result , if this could help

Comment: Doesn't really help, I'm afraid, because you haven't included any source data. Better would be to post a very small sample of the source data together with the expected results for just that sample.

Comment: i have added a data samlpe also. i hope  it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this after loading data into PowerQuery (data ... from table/range)

Click select Size and Subcategory columns, right click, group by

New Name: Count, Operation: Count rows. OK

Click select Subcategory and Count columns, right click, group by

New Name: Count1, Operation: Count rows. OK

Click select Count column

transform...pivot column

values column: Count1

sample full code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"size", "sucategoty"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
#"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"sucategoty", "Count"}, {{"Count.1", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows1", {{"Count", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows1", {{"Count", type text}}, "en-US")[Count]), "Count", "Count.1", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```